# passing parameters from an html page another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage 
- (aboutMe.html) with 
    - img(#profile)
    - h4(#title)
    - div(#txt1) 
    - button(#edit).

```
<form action="editMe.html" method="GET"> 
        <button type="button"  onclick="btntest_onclick()"> Edit </button>
        <img id="profile" src="images/pic/img1.jpg" />
        <h3 id="title"> TITLE GOES HERE</h3>
        <div id="txt1">
            <p>Who Am I ?</p> 
        </div>
</form>

function btntest_onclick() 
{   
    var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
    var txt1=document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var url = "editMe.html?title=" + encodeURIComponent(title) +  
              "&txt1="+encodeURIComponent(txt1) ;
    document.location.href = url;
}
```

When I click the button, it opens the 2nd webpage
- (editMe.html) with 
   - img(#profile)
   - textarea (#title)
   - textarea(#txt1) 
   - button(#save).

```
 <form  action="editMe.html" method="GET" onload="load()"> 
    <img id="profile" src="#" /> 
    <textarea id="title"> </textarea>
    <textarea id="txt1">  </textarea>  
 </form>

 function load()
 {  
    var url =   document.location.href,
                params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
                data = {}, 
                tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) 
    {
       tmp = params[i].split('=');
       data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = data.title;
    document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML = data.txt1;
 }
```

When the 2nd page loads, it should get the parameters title, txt1 values from the aboutMe.html. But this code is not working. Please correct the above code

Comment: Please, add code snippet and elaborate what you exactly want...

Answer (score 0):

you have several scenario:

1. try to merge two html into one.
2. pass your content & image paratemers via http request, like `editMe.html?image=IMAGE_URL&title=TITILE_CONTENT`
3. store the value into browser storage: cookie or localStorage.
4. store the value to backend server.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by this code :

**aboutMe.html**

```
<form action="editMe.html" method="GET"> 
    <button type="button"  onclick="btntest_onclick()"> Edit </button>
    <img id="profile" src="images/pic/img1.jpg" />
    <h3 id="title"> TITLE GOES HERE</h3>
    <div id="txt1">
        <p>Who Am I ?</p> 
    </div>
</form>
```

**javascript :**

```
function btntest_onclick() 
{   
   var profile=document.getElementById("profile").src;
   var title = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;
   var txt1=document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML; 

   var url = "editMe.html?profile=" + encodeURIComponent(profile)+ 
                         "&title=" + encodeURIComponent(title) +   
                         "&txt1="+encodeURIComponent(txt1) ;
    document.location.href = url;
}
```

**editMe.html **

```
<body  onload="load()">
    <form  action="editMe.html" method="GET"> 
      <img id="profile" src="#" /> 
      <textarea id="title"> </textarea>
      <textarea id="txt1">  </textarea>  
    </form>
</body>
```

**javascript :**

```
function load()
{  
    var url =   document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, 
        tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) 
    {
       tmp = params[i].split('=');
       data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById("profile").src=decodeURIComponent(data.profile);
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(data.title);
    document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(data.txt1);
}
```